# Using OpenCV-Python, how to use Python lists and Numpy arrays together efficiently?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to recreate a live video slitscan effect that I saw at an art museum.

Using opencv-python the program keeps a buffer of the last 480 frames from a webcam and then combines one row of pixels from each frame into a single image. I wrote code that produces the desired effect, but it runs a little slower than I would like. How can I optimize the algorithm by using python lists and numpy arrays together in the most efficient way?

Be aware it takes 10 seconds or so to fill the buffer before you will see the video effect.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# originally tried to use numpy to store the buffer
#buffer = np.zeros(shape=(480,480,640,3),dtype=np.uint8) 
buffer = []
slices = []
f2 = np.zeros(shape=(480,640,3),dtype=np.uint8)

display = False
rows = np.arange(480)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, -1) # flipping the frame to get the scan lines to move downward

    # originally I tried to make the buffer like this but get a memory error    
    #buffer = np.roll(buffer, -1, axis=0)
    #buffer[-1] = frame

    # using a list of numpy arrays seems to be more efficient for storing the buffer   
    buffer.append(frame)
    if(len(buffer) > 480):
        buffer = buffer[1:]

        # using a list to combine a row of pixels from each frame
        # could this be optimized with numpy arrays?
        for i in range(len(buffer)):
            slices.append(buffer[i][i])

        # convert each row to a numpy array to store final frame for display
        f2[rows] = np.array(slices[::-1])
        slices.clear()
        cv2.imshow('frame', f2)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The other idea I had would be to rewrite the code to use less buffer frames and combine several rows from each frame together, but I want to try to optimize the code with the full resolution video if possible.

Comment: Well I can offer several optimizations, first of all use a render option since your pixels nearly always will change only a bit it will improve the rendering. Than use multithreading so the next frame will be calculated as the last you is being presented. You can store only half the values you use (just some space optimization).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I can't find any info on render options though. Is there a way to only update pixels that have changed? Do you have a link for that? I am working on implementing multithreading

Comment: Well actually now I can't find it as well, maybe you can use `set_data` and `draw`. You can ask another question about this topic specifically.

Comment: I realized that the delay effect is slow by virtue of the framerate of the webcam. If I'm getting 30 fps and filling a buffer of 480 frames, that should take about 16 seconds, I rewrote the code to be able to handle different size buffers for different delay effects. eg 240 frame buffer that combines two rows of pixels from each frame or a 120 frame buffer that combines 4 rows of pixels from each frame. If anybody out there is interested let me know and I'll post more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented setting the slice size which speeds things up. It makes the image blockier, but that's ok. I like a slice size of 8. I also implemented some color mapping for fun.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

buffer = []
slices = []
height = 480
width = 640
sliceSize = 8

cap.set(4, height)
cap.set(3, width)
f2 = np.zeros(shape=(height,width,3),dtype=np.uint8)

display = False
rows = np.arange(int(height/2))

cv2.namedWindow('funnymirror', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty('funnymirror', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

c = 0
cmap = 9
cycle = True

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 0) # flipping the frame to get the scan lines to move downward

    cframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # BGR color to gray level

    if cycle:
        c= (c +1) % 255
    cframe+= c
    cframe = cv2.applyColorMap(cframe, cmap)

    frame = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.7, cframe, 0.3, 0)

    # using a list of numpy arrays seems to be more efficient for storing the buffer   
    buffer.append(frame)
    if(len(buffer) > int(height/sliceSize)):
        buffer = buffer[1:]

        # using a list to combine a row(s) of pixels from each frame
        for i in range(int(height/sliceSize)):
            for j in range(sliceSize):
                slices = buffer[i][i*sliceSize+j]
                f2[i*sliceSize+j] = np.array(slices)

        f2 = cv2.flip(f2, -1)
        cv2.imshow('funnymirror', f2)


    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord('q'): # press q to quit
        break
    # for testing purposes only change slice size on the fly
    elif key == 91: # press [ to reduces slices
        sliceSize = int(sliceSize/2)
        if sliceSize < 1:
            sliceSize = 1
        print(f'sliceSize: {sliceSize}')
    elif key == 93: # press ] to increase slices
        if sliceSize < 64:
            sliceSize*=2
        print(f'sliceSize: {sliceSize}')
    # press 1, 2, 3, or 4 to change color map
    elif key == 49: # press 1
        cmap = 2
    elif key == 50: # press 2
        cmap = 4
    elif key == 51: # press 3
        cmap = 9
    elif key == 52: #press 4
        cmap = 7
    elif key == 61: # press = to toggle cycling color map
        cycle= not cycle
        print(cycle)
    elif key!=255:
        print(key)

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```